# What does a ~$ in front of a file name in Macbook Pro mean?

Tags: macos, filesystems, macbook-pro

`ls -la` on my macbook pro terminal reveals some files with prefix `~$`.

What is this? How was this created? Can I safely delete these files?

[image: cboo]

Comment: Where are they? It might be some kind of Office backup/safety/autosave structure

Comment: they appear in my /Desktop/ directory!

Comment: For office they are temp files. the pdf could be one too if it were created with Word.

Comment: can I remove them?